# truncate syslog - is the info in that log lost irretrievably?

Tags: data-recovery, syslog

I remember using this to get syslog emptied so I could view it more easily.

But does that mean than any errors, etc in syslog are irretrievably lost?

Thanks.

```
sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unless you have backups.

`truncate`'s `-s` option is referring to size. So the size of the file was set to 0 bytes.

By default, Ubuntu will logrotate /var/log/syslog after it reaches a certain size. So perhaps the errors you're looking for are in `syslog.1`, `syslog.2.gz`, etc.